# Remove a DOM subtree in a fast way

Tags: javascript, html

I have a

```
<div id='abc'>
```

in my html page. This div has thousands of children.

Now when I do the following in JavaScript :

```
var element = document.getElementById("abc");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

This takes 12 seconds in IE11. 
Any idea on how to make this go faster ? 
I just want to destroy an element in a fast manner.
I also tried with setInnerHtml but this takes just as long...

Comment: You've said that `#abc` has thousands of child elements, but your code isremoving `#abc` itself, not its child elements. Which is it you want to do? Remove `#abc`, or *empty* it? I think we need (much) more information to work with.

Comment: Separately: Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) are for **runnable** snippets of HTML, JavaScript, and/or CSS. To just mark up something as code/markup, use the `{}` (code block) button instead.

Comment: var eid= document.getElementById("abc");
eid.outerHTML = "";
delete eid;

Comment: I want to remove the entire "abc" tag, with all of its descendants.

Comment: suresh : no speed gains from that one...

Comment: If the browser takes that long to free the DOM nodes, there is no way you can optimize it. It's the JS VM's responsibility not to block the JS context thread and do garbage collection upon idle. Blame IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE installed on my mac... but I can suggest that you begin with adding a class that hides it, and only then remove it.

Explanation:

Under the constraints of the single-threaded javascript which means that the browser can use only one core for running javascript, modern browsers will run the CSS and all other calculations on different cores. Maybe after doing that, and maybe a little 'setTimeout', the browser will be more 'prepared' for removing the item.

That's only an educated guess.

Comment: That does not make any difference.
Problem is only in IE. Chrome and FF do this in a millisecond or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

You trying to do something like this?

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function(){

  var myElement = document.getElementById('abc');

  myElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<div id='abc'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  
</div>

<button id='myButton'>teste</button>
```

Comment: yes... But with gigantic amount of tags instead of just 4.

In Chrome and FF this goes about intantantious. In IE11 it takes 12 seconds.

Comment: jquery wont speed it up

Comment: jquery can be used, but jquery can't be faster as plain javascript, as it is just a javascript wrapper.

Comment: You're right! But what if you hide the item and then remove it? Will not leave faster, but at least you will not have to wait 12 seconds.

Comment: The problem is that while the deletion is in progress the browser is completely frozen.
So making it invisible, and then removing it doesn't help....

Answer (score 0):

This *probably wont* speed anything up, but it *may* at least appear to

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var element = document.getElementById("abc");
// hide the div 
element.style.display = 'none'; 
// doing the following in a setTimeout sometimes made a big difference ... sometimes didn't! IE is tempramental
setTimeout(function() { 
    frag.appendChild(element); // this
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}, 100);
```

I no longer have IE11, Edge isn't much better at this though, and running the same code gave wildly varying results!! So, try this, I hope it helps in some way

Comment: how many direct children does that div have - is that where the 'thousands" are?

Comment: That div contains a <Table> and some other things.
The table contains thousands of rows.

Rendering the table goes pretty fast, but the deletion of the <div> takes just as long as the complete rendering. So when the user re-renders the table for the 2nd time, it takes twice as long for the results to appear.

Note, only in IE. In FF and Chrome the cleanup is in like some milli-seconds (and the rendering is also much faster, but that is just normal I think).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using innerHTML to overwrite the content instead of deleting each element? I'm not sure if this works, but it doesn't hurt to give it a try. (The original snippet was made by alexqoliveira)

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function(){

  var myElement = document.getElementById('abc');

  myElement.innerHTML = "";
}

document.getElementById('addElements').onclick = function(){
  
  var elements = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
       elements += "<p>1</p>";
    }

  var myElement = document.getElementById('abc');

  myElement.innerHTML = elements;
}
```

```html
<div id='abc'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p>
  
</div>
<button id='addElements'>Add 10000 elements</button>
<button id='myButton'>teste</button>
```